# split cell on underlined words vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Is there a way to use the split function in vba to split the cells based on underlined words? How can the delimiter be set to an underline?

```
d = Trim(cell.Value2)
arr = Split(d, " ")
```

Comment: No. Underline is a cosmetic feature and all you can pass to the split function is string.

Comment: Thanks @cyboashu. You can put it in the answers so I can accept it.

Comment: That's fine. But do you need to split on underlined chars or underlined words?

Comment: Yeah I was attempting to split on underlined chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach. A lot of error handling scope is there, but this will give you set you in right direction.

Put **`Test`** with `e` or any other char underlined in `A1` to test.

```
Public Function getArray(rng As Range)

    Dim arr()

    Dim lCtr        As Long
    Dim strText     As String
    Dim strDelim    As String

    '/ Create a delim which is qunique, so you dont miss any data.
    strDelim = "!!_<{>}##"

    For lCtr = 1 To rng.Characters.Count

        If rng.Characters(lCtr, 1).Font.Underline = XlUnderlineStyle.xlUnderlineStyleSingle Then
            '/ Splits exluding the underlined char
            strText = strText & strDelim

             '/ Splits including  the underlined char
            'strText = strText & rng.Characters(lCtr, 1).Text & strDelim

        Else
             strText = strText & rng.Characters(lCtr, 1).Text
        End If

    Next

    getArray = Split(strText, strDelim)



End Function


Sub test()
    MsgBox getArray(Cells(1, 1))(0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate the help